# Why does the solutions to a linear system of equation be equivalent to the solution to a matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Suppose we have a linear system of equations as follows:

$$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1$$
$$a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2$$
$$a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=d_3$$

The solution to the above system of linear equations is same as that for the following matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}d_1\\d_2\\d_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a specific reason for this equivalence or is it just the way the matrix objects were constructed to behave?

Also how does this specifically relate to vectors?

Comment: You may want to read through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#General_form

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference @AnuragA.